# Can I use 2 bundle in one Activity (Android Studio)?

Tags: java, android

My app is a quiz app with two levels, so I have 3 Activities:
"beginner level", "advance level" and "result".

I want the "result" Activity to take the result from the "beginner" and "advance" activities .

I try this code on "beginner" activity :

```
 Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),resultBage.class);
                    in.putExtra("correct",correct);
                    in.putExtra("wrong",wrong);
                    startActivity(in);
```

on "advance" activity :

```
Intent a = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),resultBage.class);
                a.putExtra("correct2",correct2);
                a.putExtra("wrong2",wrong2);
                startActivity(a);
```

on "result" activity :

```
Bundle bundel = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(bundel != null){
            int correct = bundel.getInt("correct",0);
            int wrong = bundel.getInt("wrong",0);

            corText.setText("correct = "+correct);
            wrongTex.setText("wrong = "+wrong);

        }


        Bundle bundle2 = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(bundle2 != null){
            int correct2 = bundle2.getInt("correct2",0);
            int wrong2 = bundle2.getInt("wrong2",0);

            corText.setText("correct = "+correct2);
            wrongTex.setText("wrong = "+wrong2);
        }
```

The problem is it's work fine if I use just one bundle what can I do?

note :  I also try StringBuffer but it's same problem

```
StringBuffer bcResult = new StringBuffer();
        bcResult.append("Correct answers: " + beginner.correct + "\n");
        StringBuffer brResult = new StringBuffer();
        brResult.append("Wrong Answers: " + beginner.wrong + "\n");
        corText.setText(bcResult);
        wrongTex.setText(brResult);
```

Comment: I didn't get clearly what you are asking. You'd like to receive the result in a unified way?

Comment: No, how would it even know which one it is?  Just use a boolean for which mode it's in, or check which keys are present.

Comment: like if the user choose beginner level and do the quiz his result  send to resultActivity and desplay it

Comment: @RyanM  How to check for keys ?

Comment: `Bundle.containsKey`

Comment: Cool, I wrote that up as an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60803401/208273) below

Comment: Since you found the answer helpful, please feel free to accept it so that others can find it more easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get `extra` data from one activity into a 3-level activity like you're trying to do. You can use `shared preferences` to save the data in one activity and then access any other activity you wish.

BTW, you can achieve in the following way what you're looking for.

You have to pass data from one activity to another and then another into the next including the data from 1st activity.

In your 2nd activity, you have to do like this:

```
Bundle bundel = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(bundel != null){
            int correct = bundel.getInt("correct",0);
            int wrong = bundel.getInt("wrong",0);

            corText.setText("correct = "+correct);
            wrongTex.setText("wrong = "+wrong);

        }

Intent a = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),resultBage.class);
a.putExtra("correct",correct);
                a.putExtra("wrong",wrong);
                a.putExtra("correct2",correct2);
                a.putExtra("wrong2",wrong2);
                startActivity(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work due to the same non-null Bundle being returned in both cases.  You should use [`Bundle.containsKey`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BaseBundle#containsKey(java.lang.String)) to check which keys are present to figure out which of the two sets of parameters is being passed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Bundle bundel = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(bundel != null){
        int correct = bundel.getInt("correct",0);
        int wrong = bundel.getInt("wrong",0);


        int correct2 = bundle2.getInt("correct2",0);
        int wrong2 = bundle2.getInt("wrong2",0);

        if(correct !=null && wrong !=null){
        corText.setText("correct = "+correct);
        wrongTex.setText("wrong = "+wrong);}else{

        corText.setText("correct = "+correct2);
        wrongTex.setText("wrong = "+wrong2);}

    }
```